# How should I handle NumberFormatException in java?

Tags: java, calendar, numberformatexception

Is there a way to handle the number(order) of `NumberFormatException`? I made a calculator using `Double` operand[], and like below, I want to write when did error occurred. When I put the input "2+k", the message saying that "operand[1] has the wrong input." should come out. How should I do like that?

Comment: You may want to validate that the input is numeric before passing it to your calculator. If you search on SO for something like check if a string is numeric you'll find lots of examples.

Comment: Apparently the `calculate()` method converts the operands to doubles?  It may be possible to catch the exceptions there seperately and rethrow them with the explicit message that you want.  Like `throw new NumberFormatException(String.format("operand[%d] has the wrong input.", operandIndex));`.  Then you could just catch the `NumberFormatException` here and print its message.  Like Paul's answer but without validating the input yourself.  Just stuff them in a `double` and catch/rethrow the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, replace the line

```
System.out.println("operand[] has the wrong input.");
```

with the line

```
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
```

Now you can pass a message when you throw the exception in the `MyCalculator.calculate()` method using the `NumberFormatException(String)` constructor. It would look something like this:

```
calculate(String expression)
{
    //validate input code
    //...

    //if operand 0 not valid
    throw new NumberFormatException("operand 0 has the wrong input");

    //if operand 1 not valid
    throw new NumberFormatException("operand 1 has the wrong input");

    //rest of calculate method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could define a new exception. As for example `CalculatorException` which could contain more specific information about calculations, as for example which operand is incorrect. Or you could even define one more exception like `IllegalOperandException` which could extend  `CalculatorException`. And then your method `calculate` could be declared to throw a `CalculatorException`. In conclusion, the idea is to define a new hierarchy of exceptions to give information more related to the domain of your problem.

And then, your code could be so:

```
try {
    System.out.println("result: " + MyCalculator.calculate(expression));
    System.out.println();
} catch(CalculatorException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```